# Adding project reference in VS Code for C++/CLI project

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-code, c++-cli

I am currently using VS Code with the C/C++ extension to develop a C++/CLI wrapper module for native code. I am having trouble adding a project reference. I know it is possible in Visual Studio.

However, is it possible to add a Project Reference for a C++/CLI project in VS Code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I require should not change the Visual Studio environment. As it is used as the main build environment.

The current workaround that I have done is to add the Project Referenced files as `ForcedIncludes` in my `c_cpp_properties.json` file. This solves my issue and changes nothing that will cause the Visual Studio environment to fail to build.